# Get only those polls which user did not vote yet using Firestore query

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore for our backend solution. My app concept is simple, user will vote on polls one by one. My question is how i structure data models for this concept. User will only vote on those polls that he did not vote yet. I am stuck on this point that how i filter polls that user did not voted because firestore query not supported **!=** operator.

[image: Poll collection document structure]

My Query for fetch polls is

```
   db.collection(POLLS)
        .whereArrayContains(
            Poll.AGE_RANGE,
            DateTimeUtils.calculateAge(user?.dateOfBirth)// integer value
        )
        .whereEqualTo("gender.${user?.gender}", true)
        .orderBy(Poll.CREATED_AT)
        .limit(QUEUE_LIMIT)
```

Comment: can you post the database structure you used for Firebase ?

Comment: @Ashish i updated my question please have a look thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would get the polls where the user voted in a set A. Then in the client get the set with all polls (let's call it B). Do a set difference B-A. You get all polls where the user did not vote.

Comment: thanks for replied, I understand your point. But now my question is when polls data increase in future let say 1000+ then Is it good way to do filter polls locally ? I need `addSnapshotListener` callback so that i can get updates when some polls time expired.